# Identification of 404 picture from Stack Exchange Chat

Tags: story-identification, star-trek, star-trek-tng

The following picture appears on the [404 error page](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100000) on [Stack Exchange Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/):

[image: Star Trek?]

My minimal knowledge of Star Trek tells me that these men are Captain Jean-Luc Picard (on the right), First Officer William Riker (on the left), and Lieutenant Worf (in the background), officers on the *Enterprise* during Star Trek TNG.

But **where does this picture originate?** Is it a screenshot taken from an episode of Star Trek? If so, which one? A Youtube clip including this scene would be great, if anyone has one!

<sub>Bonus points if you can explain why they're wearing funny hats: this picture's [title](http://cdn-chat.sstatic.net/chat/img/404_funny_hats.jpg) is "404_funny_hats.jpg".</sub>

Comment: I did a reverse Google image search... :-P

Comment: Whether this is a real dupe might actually be questionable, as the other question was "Is this photoshopped?"

Comment: the answer to the linked dupe not only explains that it's photoshopped but also what episode it's from.

Comment: This is a picture of three men who love their mothers and aren't afraid of anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like, the last time this image got asked after, people figured it came from [here](https://badassrainbows.wordpress.com/2010/05/16/128/). And the original shot is a teaser image for "Q Who":

[image: Q Who image]

Comment: Love the way there's a cursor hanging over the image enough to annoy me!

Comment: It didn't bother me until you pointed it out. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Mazura Glad to be of service

Comment: If it bothers you, you can replace the image with one with no cursor. [here](https://scontent-ams3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xfa1/v/t1.0-9/314099_437888199594135_802679057_n.jpg?oh=938c7f0c9662995f734ca545e1e70898&oe=568E0898).